# Redux Saga Twice call in async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I am building react-native app with redux saga. I think I am doing something wrong. This may be because I don't know much about how saga works. But the part I'm trying to understand is why you need to call twice.

My button for first call.

```js
    <Button
                loading={pending}
                onPress={this.handleLogin}
                containerStyle={styles.margin}
              />
```

My function for button.

```js
 handleLogin = () => {
    const { screenProps: {t} } = this.props;
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    this.props.dispatch(signInWithEmail({email, password}));
```

My actions

```js
import * as Actions from './constants';

export function signInWithEmail({email, password}) {
  return {
    email,
    password,
    type: Actions.SIGN_IN_WITH_EMAIL,
  };
}
```

My Saga Listeners

```js
export default function* authSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(Actions.SIGN_IN_WITH_EMAIL, signInWithEmailSaga);
  yield takeEvery(Actions.SIGN_IN_WITH_MOBILE, signInWithMobileSaga);
  yield takeEvery(Actions.SIGN_UP_WITH_EMAIL, signUpWithEmailSaga);
  yield takeEvery(Actions.SIGN_IN_WITH_GOOGLE, signInWithGoogleSaga); 
  ...
}
```

My saga function

```js
function* signInWithEmailSaga({email, password}) {
  try {
    const language = yield select(languageSelector);
    let loginRequest = {
      email,
      password,
    };
    const token = globalConfig.getToken();
    const responseLogin = yield call(loginWithEmail, loginRequest);

    if (!responseLogin.user) {
      console.log('if not user', responseLogin);
      yield put({
        type: Actions.SIGN_IN_WITH_EMAIL_ERROR,
        payload: {
          message: responseLogin.message,
        },
      });
    } else {
      yield call(setUser, responseLogin);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // yield call(handleError, e)
    yield put({
      type: Actions.SIGN_IN_WITH_EMAIL_ERROR,
      payload: {
        message: e.message,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

I send an email and password to the server to get a response. I making this via
`yield call(loginWithEmail, loginRequest);`

if signInWithEmailSaga function contains only console log line only trigger twice.
This is a big mistake for me. I am spend 20 hours but I didnt.

I used takeLatest, takeEvery and changed actions name. Same result.

This is my redux store and saga middleware setup.

```js
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import immutableTransform from 'redux-persist-transform-immutable';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  transforms: [immutableTransform()],
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: [
    // 'test',
    'common',
    'category',
    'classified',
    //'auth',
  ],
};

const composeEnhancers =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? composeWithDevTools({realtime: true})
    : compose;
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export default () => {
  const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));
  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, enhancer);
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  // then run the saga
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  return {store, persistor};
};
```

I will be very glad if you give information about where the problem is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that your saga listeners are getting registered again when you change route and land back on the same page

Solution would be to de-register the saga when the container corresponding to that particular route is un-mounted